# Starting operating system development

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system

I want to make a new operating system for PC. I know C, but have no idea about in which compiler can I do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Compiler choice is about the least important aspect of starting an OS from scratch.

Comment: If you are going to customize an existing operating system like Linux, let us know which one, and we will be able to help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry so much about the compiler at this point (gcc would be fine though). You need to think about all the other problems involving getting an OS to run. I strongly suggest you dive in to some of the communities around "hobby OSes". This will give you an idea of what's really involved in OS development. Also take a look at some alternative OSes that are already out there, like [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) and perhaps [Haiku](http://www.haiku-os.org/). OS development isn't something you can do alone and expect to make progress overnight, but it's a worthy endeavor in any case. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a Personal Computer of the sort of configuration that could run windows or an intel build of linux, then any compiler that worked on your host platform could do it but I would think you would probably be better off with GCC to be able to customise it a lot, especially as you will have to write quite a lot of libraries and a host system for transferring the binaries onto your host machine (the machine that will run your os).

But as a literal answer, any you can run can.

Comment: I would also say that if you are having problems with that decision, you may have future problems as that is a trivial issue compared with the other ones you will face. May be worth your while getting a book on it.

Comment: "better off with GCC to be able to customise it a lot" -- If you do need to customize your compiler (and I don't know why you would, for this), I think GCC would be a lousy choice.  It's huge and complex, even for a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As for the compiler, I'd recommend `GCC`, because it's the most supported, and almost every hobby OS development tutorial you will find on the internet would have instructions for using it.

And, assuming you are a beginner in this field, you should probably look at the osdev Wiki.

It's great, and, unlike most other tutorials on the net, the information you will find there is actually legitimate.

There is also a forum there. It's full of friendly people willing to help you.

In my opinion, OSDeving would be not that hard if you follow the bare bones tutorials of the OSDev wiki.
Keep patience, as OSDeving is not a beginner's task. Make sure you know the assembly language before you dive in it.